What are the schemes and the handlers and how are they related?
I am trying to understand how the Microsoft Identity package for authenticating users works.
It isn't clear to me what exactly schemes and handlers are and how they are used with each other.
I faced those two terms when I was learning how to use the Microsoft Identity package for authenticating users. I tried to find an answer for that myself but it still isn't clear so I tried to check tutorials for authenticating users without this package so that I get a more clear view about what this package does behind the scenes.
There are some points that are still hazy for me:

What are schemes and handlers and how are they related?
What is the string authenticationType passed to the constructor of ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim>? claims, string? authenticationType), and is it related to the schemes and handlers or not?
What is the scheme that is used when signing in a user using the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure) which is provided by the identity package?


Claim's authenticationType parameter isn't really used anymore - I think it was only relevant back in .NET Framework 2.x-4.x days if you were using WS-Security or Windows Identity Foundation. I've only ever seen the property be empty or holding some short stub value when using ASP.NET Core's OIDC lib.

"What is the scheme that is used when signing in a user using the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync" - That depends on how you configured it - so we need to see your Startup or Program code (i.e. your ConfigureServices and Configure methods - or equivalents) to give you an answer.


What are schemes and handlers and how are they related?

An authentication scheme is a specific way to authenticate a client or request.
An authentication handler is a class or middleware-function that ASP.NET Core uses to perform that authentication process on a request.
Within the context of ASP.NET Core 3.1 or later, the most common authentication-schemes you'll run into are:

Cookies - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies (default name: "Cookies")
OAuth2 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth (no default-name; often implies using JWTs to access other resources, while using Cookies to store those JWT tokens, and other auth info, for web-browser users)
OIDC - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (as with OAuth2, ASP.NET Core will combine this scheme with Cookies so web-browser users can use stateless auth)
JWT - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer - use this scheme if your ASP.NET Core code is a web-service ("web API") - it is not suitable for use in MVC web-applications with web-browser users and if you aren't using OAuth2 or OIDC. Do not use this scheme directly if you're using OAuth2/OIDC even if they're using JWT, because those other scheme's libraries take care of a lot of responsibilities you'd have to write by hand here (such as the cryptrographic keys for JWT verification).


What is the (string authenticationType parameter given to the constructor of ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim>? claims, string? authenticationType) and is it related to the schemes and handlers or not?

If you aren't using ASP.NET Core Identity then this is nothing you need to worry about as it isn't really used anywhere anymore; and the current (.NET 8) documentation only makes references to old-school schemes like HTTP Basic, NTLM, Kerberos, and Passport.
"Passport" was Microsoft's first-attempt at their own first-party semi-federated SSO thing around 1999 - it was killed-off sometime around 2003-ish, which was after ASP.NET first launched, which is why ASP.NET (for .NET Framework) has vestigial references to it still. Passport's successor was launched around 2005 as "Windows Live ID" which eventually turned into today's "Microsoft Account" around 2011-ish?
But if you are using ASP.NET Core Identity and you're using multiple authenticatio-schemes, then SignInManager (and some other places) use this property to check to see if the current request user is/was authenticated with a specific SignInManager by using the SignInManager.AuthenticationScheme property value which you configure during startup).

What is the scheme that is used when signing in a user using the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure) which is provided by the identity package?

According to the source-code, if you use MapIdentityApi with ASP.NET Core Identity, then SignInManager.AuthenticationScheme will be set to either "Identity.Application" or "Identity.Bearer" (depending on whether ASP.NET Core Identity is configured for Cookies or Bearer-tokens respectively).
If you don't use MapIdentityApi - but use ASP.NET Core Identity's AddDefaultIdentity method, then uses "Identity.External" for the DefaultSignInScheme and "Identity.Application" for its own Cookies scheme.

This makes it more clear, but there still something that I want to inquire about in the cookie based authentication. The user is given a token inside a cookie and this token is used to authenticate that user in every subsequent request, how is this done without associating the token to the user in a database?

@HossamZaki The token is cryptographically signed by the IdP: your application’s authx middleware will validate the signature with the public key published by the IdP. No “database” of any kind is needed by the RP (I.e. your application). It’s all built-on trust: the RP trusts the IdP to know who its users are.

thanks for making it clear, appreciated help.

In asp.net core Scheme is a named configuration that defines how an application authenticates.It can also be understood that the authentication scheme is the name of the Handler, and it is also an option for configuring a specific instance of the handler. Authentication schemes are associated with corresponding Handlers, which are responsible for actually executing the authentication logic. For example, you can configure a scheme for Cookie authentication and a scheme for JWT authentication.
Handlers are types that implement scheme behavior and are mainly responsible for authenticating users. Each handler is associated with a specific authentication scheme and is responsible for processing authentication requests for that scheme. For example, the Cookie handler handles Cookie-based authentication, while the JWT handler handles JWT-based authentication.
In ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim>? claims, string? authenticationType) Initializes a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity class using the specified claims and authentication type,where string authenticationType indicates the authentication type used.
SigninManager is used to provide an API for user login, which contains the authentication scheme used for login, and the default is ApplicationScheme  which used to identify application authentication cookies, PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure) is one of the api methods. It indicates Attempts to sign in the specified userName and password combination as an asynchronous operation, Therefore, when using the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method, the ASP.NET Core Identity scheme is a Cookie-based authentication scheme by default.
